# Can not connect to local server using dnsmasq with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dnsmasq

I have a rails app which i am trying to run on local environment with the help of dnsmasq. When i start the rails server, it starts without any error showing:

```
[18973] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[18973] * Version 3.12.1 (ruby 2.6.3-p62), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
[18973] * Min threads: 10, max threads: 10
[18973] * Environment: development
[18973] * Process workers: 1
[18973] * Phased restart available
[18973] * Listening on tcp:0.0.0.0:3001
[18973] * Listening on ssl:0.0.0.0:3000 cert=config/ssl.crt&key=config/ssl.key&verify_mode=none
[18973] Use Ctrl-C to stop
[18973] * Starting control server on unix:///tmp/puma-status-1580448227758-18973
[18973] - Worker 0 (pid: 19010) booted, phase: 0
```

I did start dnsmasq service and this is its status

```
● dnsmasq.service - dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-01-31 11:05:18 IST; 2s ago
  Process: 19529 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq systemd-stop-resolvconf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 19605 ExecStartPost=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq systemd-start-resolvconf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 19596 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq systemd-exec (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 19595 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --test (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 19604 (dnsmasq)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dnsmasq.service
           └─19604 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq -x /run/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.pid -u dnsmasq -r /run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf -7 /etc/dnsmasq.d,.dpkg-dist,.dpkg-old

Jan 31 11:05:18 BEAST dnsmasq[19595]: dnsmasq: syntax check OK.
Jan 31 11:05:18 BEAST dnsmasq[19604]: started, version 2.79 cachesize 150
Jan 31 11:05:18 BEAST dnsmasq[19604]: DNS service limited to local subnets
Jan 31 11:05:18 BEAST dnsmasq[19604]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus i18n IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP conntrack ipset auth DNSSEC
Jan 31 11:05:18 BEAST dnsmasq[19604]: no servers found in /run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf, will retry
Jan 31 11:05:18 BEAST dnsmasq[19604]: read /etc/hosts - 7 addresses
Jan 31 11:05:18 BEAST dnsmasq[19604]: reading /run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf
Jan 31 11:05:18 BEAST dnsmasq[19604]: using nameserver 127.0.0.53#53
Jan 31 11:05:18 BEAST dnsmasq[19605]: /etc/resolvconf/update.d/libc: Warning: /etc/resolv.conf is not a symbolic link to /run/resolvconf/resol
Jan 31 11:05:18 BEAST systemd[1]: Started dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
```

I have added dev file at location /etc/resolver/ with its content as

```
file: /etc/resolver/dev
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

I have also added one line to config file at location /etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
address=/.dev/127.0.0.1
```

but i can't connect to server from the browser.

Here is my `/etc/resolv.conf` file while dnsmasq is running

```
nameserver 172.16.10.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

And this is the change that i have made in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` file the rest of it is default

```
address=/.dev/127.0.0.1
```

Output of `netsatat -na | grep LISTEN` while my rails server is running along with dnsmasq

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

**UPDATE for dig commands:**

Output of `dig www.example.dev`

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.11-Ubuntu <<>> www.example.dev
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 18574
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.example.dev.       IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
dev.            300 IN  SOA ns-tld1.charlestonroadregistry.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 1 21600 3600 259200 300

;; Query time: 321 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon Feb 03 13:28:54 IST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 146
```

Output of `dig @127.0.0.1 www.example.dev`

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.11-Ubuntu <<>> @127.0.0.1 www.example.dev
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 48569
;; flags: qr aa rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.example.dev.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.example.dev.    0   IN  A   127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Feb 03 13:29:50 IST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 53
```

Output of `dig example.dev`

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.11-Ubuntu <<>> example.dev
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 27586
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.dev.       IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
dev.            211 IN  SOA ns-tld1.charlestonroadregistry.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 1 21600 3600 259200 300

;; Query time: 271 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon Feb 03 13:38:03 IST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 142
```

Output of `dig @127.0.0.1 example.dev`

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.11-Ubuntu <<>> @127.0.0.1 example.dev
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 36026
;; flags: qr aa rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.dev.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.dev.    0   IN  A   127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Feb 03 13:38:09 IST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 49
```

Comment: What URL do you enter in the browser? This browser runs on the same box with Rails app and dnsmasq? If not, are the box with browser and the box with Rails on the same IP subnet?

Comment: I want to run localhost with .dev extension. So I'm using www.example.dev:3000 in my browser. How to know browser is running on the same box with dnsmasq and server? Please, guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have only one computer (or virtual machine) with development environment running Rails application and your browser window. So you don't need `dnsmasq` at all, just add to your `/etc/hosts` file

```
127.0.0.1 www.example.dev
```

Then you point the browser to `http://www.example.dev:3001` or `https://www.example.dev:3000` because you have configured two ports (3000 for ssl, and 3001 for non-ssl access) - see `puma` startup messages.

**UPDATE**

As you want `dnsmasq`:

1. File `/etc/resolver/dev` should have only one line (no colon there!)

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

2. Seems that `dnsmasq` binds to `127.0.0.53` (see third line from the bottom of `dnsmasq` statup messages), not to `127.0.0.1`

Comment: I actually have multiple subdomains and so i need dnsmasq. I tried changing /etc/hosts file with 127.0.0.1 *.example.dev but it still does not work

Comment: /etc/hosts doesn't allow wildcard domain names. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Oh! i am really sorry there was a typo in the question asked and there is no colon in the file i have. As I am very new to using dnsmasq, how do i fix it as you mentioned?

Comment: Please show your `/etc/resolv.conf`, `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` and the output of `netstat -na | grep LISTEN` when `dnsmasq` is running

Comment: I updated the question with both files and output of netstat. Please have a look

Comment: Your configuration seems to be ok. Let's check if `dnsmasq` resolves correctly. Please provide the output of `dig www.example.dev` and `dig @127.0.0.1 www.example.dev`. Also `dig example.dev` and `dig @127.0.0.1 example.dev`.

Comment: Well, are you on Linux or OS X? Linux doesn't support forwarders through `/etc/resolver` files

Comment: I am on Linux. I have updated question with outputs of dig commands. What should i  do since i am using Linux?

Comment: Just move `nameserver 127.0.0.1` to the first line in `/etc/resolv.conf`. You may also delete `/etc/resolver` directory as it's not being used.

Comment: then run `dig www.example.dev` again, it should state `;;SERVER: 127.0.0.1` at the bottom

Comment: it states ;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)

Comment: Please make sure that `/etc/resolv.conf` is not a symlink. Make sure that first `nameserver` in this file is `127.0.0.1`. Restart systemd-resolved service if you have this one. After that make sure that first `nameserver` line of `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` points to `127.0.0.1`. Run `dig example.dev` again and see what `SERVER` states.

Comment: It worked for me after i disabled the symlink. Thank you for helping me out